# SELECT2 Input Box Styling

Tags: html, jquery-select2, ui-select2, angularjs-select2

I am using a SELECT2 Input box.  I need help trying to change the color (to white) of the "X" that would remove the tag from the field.  I have included a fiddle with some sample code.

The below is just some sample code.  I am using an input box with angular utilizing ui-select2 functionality.  I figure is someone can figure out below, I can at least translate it to what I need.  Thanks!

```
<select multiple id="e1" style="width:300px">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
    <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
    <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" >Select All
```

Some Script:

```
$("#e1").select2();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jimfromthegym/jEADR/1112/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the "X" is actually an image: select2.png
If you check your browser web tools network tab you can see this external resource loaded.

I'm assuming it is part of the select2 plugin you are using. If you can find this image in the source of the plugin and change the color manually using an image editor that would be your quick fix/change.

Comment: Ahh, I see it now.  Any ideas on good image editors to do this?

Comment: I'm not too savvy with image editing, but for a job like this I use GIMP (GNU Image Manipulation Program). It's like a freeware version of photoshop. I would suggest just using MSPaint, but I don't think it supports alpha layers on .png (which you'll need to keep the background of this image transparent)